# How can I change the entry point procedure from "WinMain" to "main" or any custom function?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I have read a lot about how to change the `WinMain` entry point procedure, some say you can change the entry point from the linker and some others say you can put the `WinMain` into DLL (`dllMain`) and so on.

Honestly, I am confused. I believe that there are one or more ways to change the entry point procedure to a custom procedure because there are some examples like MFC don't have a direct `WinMain` function and the Qt framework also has a custom entry point procedure it's similar to the console application `main` function `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, so, there are ways as I expected.

I want a whatever way to replace/change the entry point procedure for GUI application on Windows from the traditional procedural `WinMain` to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` like Qt or even any other custom function but it must be compatible with (MS, GCC, Clang) compilers.

```
///////////Windows main/////////////
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR cmdParam, int cmdShow){

}
///////////Console main and Qt framework////////////
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
}
//////////MFC////////////
class CMyFrame : public CFrameWnd {
   public:
      CMyFrame() {}
};

class CExample : public CWinApp {
   BOOL InitInstance() {}
};
CExample theApp;
```

How do I do that?

Comment: It is tricky using something other than `main` or `WinMain` because those are the entry points called by the runtime library after it has completed its initialisation.  The MSVC linker does allow you to specify the entry point on the command line (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2019), but then that would bypass the runtime library initialisation code and that would break your application.

Comment: *I want a whatever way to replace/change the entry point procedure for GUI application on Windows* - and sense ? what do you want to get? what is this for ?

Comment: @RbMm: I am trying to create a GUI library but I would not the library to be complicated so I want to make the entry point to be something familiar to the users for example `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` function instead `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR cmdParam, int cmdShow)`.

Comment: @LionKing -if say true i not understand you at all. what is different `main` or `WinMain` ? how some users related here, why lib at all implement entry point.. but what you want very easy do, if you understand my answer - `/ENTRY: mainCRTStartup` - this is obvious

Comment: In your GUI library include a WinMain function that does whatever it does and then calls a function called main that you don't implement.  Then when the user of the library makes a main function, it just works.  Then the loader just calls your WinMain function without any special sauce.  The main thing is that the user of the library needs to compile their program as a windows executable instead of a console program so that your WinMain gets called.

Answer (score 1):

entry point of *exe* can by any function with signature

```
ULONG CALLBACK ep(void* )
```

possible and use `ULONG CALLBACK ep()` - despite on *x86* will be wrong stack pointer (*esp*) after return, this not lead to error, because windows just call *`ExitThread`* after entry return, if it return control at all - usually it call *`ExitProcess`* instead return.

the name of this entry point of course not play any role at all - it can be any valid *c/c++* name. entry point found/called not by name but by [*`AddressOfEntryPoint`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) offset from [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header64)

but when we build *PE* - we need tell linker name of this function, for it can set *AddressOfEntryPoint*, but this info (name of function) used only during build process (not used in runtime)

different linkers of course have different options for do this, *link.exe* have option [`/ENTRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2019). this option is optional and by default, the starting address is a function name from the C run-time library.

if `/ENTRY:MyEntry` explicitly stated - it used as is - *`MyEntry`* will be used as entry point. if no `/ENTRY` option set - used default:

if `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` set - used *`mainCRTStartup`* or if it not found *`wmainCRTStartup`*

if `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` set - used *`WinMainCRTStartup`* or if it not found *`wWinMainCRTStartup`*

but in most case *c/c++* developers use *CRT* libraries. regardless of whether static or dynamic linking used with *CRT* - some lib code always statically linked with your *exe* and this code containing function which you used as entry point. for ms windows crt - this is *`mainCRTStartup`* or *`wmainCRTStartup`* (for console apps), *`WinMainCRTStartup`* or *`wWinMainCRTStartup`* for gui apps.

in all this 4 functions - called **hardcoded** function by name

- *`mainCRTStartup`* call *`main`*
- *`wmainCRTStartup`* call *`wmain`*
- *`WinMainCRTStartup`* call *`WinMain`*
- *`wWinMainCRTStartup`* call *`wWinMain`*

of course called function must be implemented somewhere in your code or in another lib code. for example if you use *MFC* - it implement *`wWinMain`* by self and called your code in another way ( via calling virtual functions on object which you override - `InitApplication` and `InitInstance`)

if back to question how change name of your custom entry point - but for what ? you really not need change name. you need only understand how your entry point is called. if you understand this - you can do almost all.

---

assume we want use *`main`* as "entry point". i take this in quotes because we really want have real entry point in *CRT* code and we want that *CRT* code call exactly *`main`* function.

possible ? simply !
set `/ENTRY: mainCRTStartup` linker option. so *`mainCRTStartup`* will be real entry point and it call *`main`*.

another question, i personally think that this is senseless trick, which nothing change and nothing give

---

also possible simply call `main` from `WinMain`

```
typedef struct
{
    int newmode;
} _startupinfo;

 /* 
 * new mode flag -- when set, makes malloc() behave like new()
 */

EXTERN_C _CRTIMP int __cdecl _query_new_mode( );
EXTERN_C _CRTIMP int __cdecl _set_new_mode( _In_ int _NewMode);

EXTERN_C
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __getmainargs(__out int * _Argc, 
                              __deref_out_ecount(*_Argc) char *** _Argv,
                              __deref_out_opt char *** _Env, 
                              __in int _DoWildCard,
                              __in _startupinfo * _StartInfo);

int __cdecl main(__in int _Argc, __in_ecount_z(_Argc) char ** _Argv, ...);

int CALLBACK WinMain( _In_ HINSTANCE , _In_opt_ HINSTANCE , _In_ LPSTR , _In_ int  )
{
    int _Argc, r;
    char ** _Argv;
    char ** _Env;
    _startupinfo  _StartInfo { _query_new_mode( ) };
    if (!(r = __getmainargs(&_Argc, &_Argv, &_Env, 0, &_StartInfo)))
    {
        r = main(_Argc, _Argv, _Env);
        if (_Argv) free(_Argv);
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220827/discussion-on-answer-by-rbmm-how-can-i-change-the-entry-point-procedure-from-wi).

Answer (score 0):

> it must be compatible with (MS, GCC, Clang) compilers

How you do that depends on your compiler. Most of them will have some flags to choose which "subsystem" (the Windows term) you are targeting and even customize the entry point manually.

Put another way, there is no standard way of doing so because this is outside the scope of the C++ standard.

Having said that, some compilers provide the means to emulate the flags of other compilers. For instance, Clang can imitate Microsoft's.